# Add Spring Security Filter dynamically

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

The application I am currently working on allows end users to set up different security settings based on their needs. For example, I am working on adding SAML support but not all of our users will need SAML.

I want to add the SAML filters to the Spring Security filter chain when a user enables SAML in their settings. I don't want to clutter of the main programs `HttpSecurity` configuration with SAML filters and paths when most instances won't require SAML at all.

I've tried autowiring any bean that remotely relates to Spring Security but I can't find any that allow me to set anything (`springSecurityFilterChain` for example)